# error when the android studio run an application

Tags: flutter

problem with runing

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Failed to install the following SDK components:
> build-tools;30.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3
> Install the missing components using the SDK manager in Android Studioo

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try to accept the licences before building.

Per According to [Android SDK docs](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdkmanager) you can use the following command depending on the sdkmanager location:

```
yes | sdkmanager --licenses
```

GNU/Linux Distributions:

```
yes | ~/Android/Sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
```

macOS:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home
yes | ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
```

%ANDROID_HOME%/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
Flutter:

```
> flutter config --android-sdk 'path-of-android-sdk'(only for ubuntu user)
> flutter doctor --android-licenses
```